# Apply function to certain attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex, url

I have a javascript function which converts all relative urls to absolute urls.

```
function rel2Abs(_relPath, _base);
//_relPath the relative path
//_base the base url
```

Now I want to **apply** this **function to all href and src values in** a document **string** (jQuery post ajax response).

What would be the simplest solution to do this?
Is there a way of solving this using regex?

Edit: jQuery is available

Comment: What your ajax reponse looks like?

Comment: its just a stringified ordinary html document "<html><head>..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery to parse your html string using `$.parseHTML` and wrap the resulting dom nodes array in a jQuery object. In theory, you can pass in html to `$` directly, but you might have issues if your HTML starts with plain text.

Here's a utility function you can use:

```
!function($) {
    $.extend({
        fromHtml: function (html) {
            return $($.parseHTML(html));
        }
    });
}(jQuery);
```

Then you can simply do something like:

```
var urlConverter = function (i, v) {
        return rel2abs(v, 'yourBaseUrl');
    },
    $dom = $.fromHtml(yourHtml)
        .filter('[href]').attr('href', urlConverter).end()
        .filter('[src]').attr('src', urlConverter).end();
```

Comment: works fine I just had to replace find by filter as Rory mentioned below (y)

Comment: Sorry, @Musa mentioned it not Rory

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your AJAX response is text/html, you can wrap it in a jQuery object and perform DOM manipulation on it. Something like this:

```
// in success handler -- assuming 'data' = returned value
var $data = $(data);
$('a', $data).each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', function(val) {
        return rel2abs(val, baseUrl); // assuming baseUrl is a global
    })
});
$data.appendTo(someElement);
```

`img` elements would follow the same pattern, just changing `$('img', $dom)` and `$(this).attr('src', fn)`.

Comment: $('link', $data) returns an empty result even if there are <link> elements in my document. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `filter` instead of `find`($('link', $data)) since link tags are in the head tag which is stripped out so they will be at top level in the jQuery object.